# Under x11, how to install a hook procedure that monitors event posted to a event queue

Tags: x11

Under x11, how to install a hook procedure that monitors messages posted to a event queue. As we know we can use the func SetWindowsHookEx and WH_GETMESSAGE hook procedure under win32.

Comment: There are no general-purpose event hooks under X11, and nothing similar to `WH_GETMESSAGE`.

If you describe the real problem you're trying to solve, perhaps someone will be able to suggest a solution appropriate for X11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you need [XSelectInput](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSelectInput.html). When some event occurs server-side, xserver decides who to notify based on target window event mask. Unlike other window attributes, every client changing window event mask has its own copy and server notifies all clients who set window event mask. This way you can select, for example Exposure event mask for root window and receive events whenever root window rectangle is invalidated - similar to setting WM_PAINT hook in win32 api.